# JQuery Checkbox Filter Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this work with already existing javascripts on my webpage. This is what I want http://jsfiddle.net/tkLK6/

But when adding it to my already existing javascript I cannot get it to "filter".

This is what is already existing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function() {
        var src = $('#productsBtn').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
        $('#productsBtn').attr("src", src);

        $(".sf-menu #homeNav a")
            .mouseover(function() { 
                var src = $('#homeBtn').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
                $('#homeBtn').attr("src", src);
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
                var src = $('#homeBtn').attr("src").replace("_over.png", ".png");
                $('#homeBtn').attr("src", src);
            });

        $(".sf-menu #aboutNav a")
            .mouseover(function() { 
                var src = $('#aboutBtn').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
                $('#aboutBtn').attr("src", src);
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
                var src = $('#aboutBtn').attr("src").replace("_over.png", ".png");
                $('#aboutBtn').attr("src", src);
            });

        $(".sf-menu #warrantyNav a")
            .mouseover(function() { 
                var src = $('#warrantyBtn').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
                $('#warrantyBtn').attr("src", src);
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
                var src = $('#warrantyBtn').attr("src").replace("_over.png", ".png");
                $('#warrantyBtn').attr("src", src);
            });

        $(".sf-menu #solutionsNav a")
            .mouseover(function() { 
                var src = $('#solutionsBtn').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
                $('#solutionsBtn').attr("src", src);
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
                var src = $('#solutionsBtn').attr("src").replace("_over.png", ".png");
                $('#solutionsBtn').attr("src", src);
            });

        $(".sf-menu #technicalNav a")
            .mouseover(function() { 
                var src = $('#technicalBtn').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
                $('#technicalBtn').attr("src", src);
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
                var src = $('#technicalBtn').attr("src").replace("_over.png", ".png");
                $('#technicalBtn').attr("src", src);
            });

        $(".sf-menu #contactNav a")
            .mouseover(function() { 
                var src = $('#contactBtn').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
                $('#contactBtn').attr("src", src);
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
                var src = $('#contactBtn').attr("src").replace("_over.png", ".png");
                $('#contactBtn').attr("src", src);
            });

        $(".sf-menu #partnerNav a")
            .mouseover(function() { 
                var src = $('#partnerBtn').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
                $('#partnerBtn').attr("src", src);
            })
            .mouseout(function() {
                var src = $('#partnerBtn').attr("src").replace("_over.png", ".png");
                $('#partnerBtn').attr("src", src);
            });
    });

    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });

    $('.tab-parent').each(function(){
        $(this).find(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
        $(this).find("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
        $(this).find(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    });

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        var parents = $(this).parentsUntil('.tab-parent').parent();
        $("li", parents).removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content", parents).hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

                    jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
                });
```

Any ideas of how to get it to work with both? When I do it the results will not filter. (See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkLK6/302/))

Comment: Why are you nesting document ready calls?

Comment: The already existing javascript is not my work... It is what i have to work with.